# How to prevent mod_proxy modifying redirect headers?

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, apache2.4

I'm trying to set up a proxy to our existing site under a different URL.  I use mod_proxy to make http://z-m-s.co.uk appear to be http://dev1.zaomengshe.com.

Problem is when we come to redirect to a payment gateway.  The redirect header is also changing mapi.alipay.com to z-m-s.co.uk.

I didn't even realise mod_proxy would change headers like that, and I don't understand why it would modify headers outside either of our domains.

Can someone explain how to turn off modification of headers?  We don't have any internal redirects so it's OK to turn it off completely, although better would be to have it modify internal redirects while leaving external redirects intact.

Here's my configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName z-m-s.co.uk 
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / http://dev1.zaomengshe.com/

    <Location />
        ProxyPassReverse /
        ProxyHTMLEnable On
        RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
    </Location>

    Substitute "s|dev1.zaomengshe.com|z-m-s.co.uk|iq"
    SetOutputFilter SUBSTITUTE
    LogLevel debug

    CacheEnable disk /
    CacheRoot "/var/cache/mod_proxy"
    CacheDirLevels 3
    CacheDirLength 5
    CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
    CacheMaxFileSize 100000000 
    CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On 
    CacheMaxExpire 1209600 
    CacheIgnoreQueryString On 

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I just didn't know what ProxyPassReverse does.  It's exactly responsible for modifying redirects.  So just removing that line did the trick.